# mysql summary column using nested query

Tags: mysql

I need a select statement to return different summary columns.

Here is the basic structure:

```
Column 1: Date
Column 2: Owner
Column 3: Sum of "Hours" where "Status" = 'billable'
Column 4: Sum of "Hours" where "Status" = 'non billable'
```

So a sample return row would look like...

```
Date | Owner | Billable | Non Billable
2019-01-01 Bob Smith 17.54 13.66
2019-01-01 Joe Johnson 23.17 16.54
```

Here is my code. It is returning a total of all owners hours for the entire date range instead of by owner by date.

```
SELECT "Date", "Owner",

(SELECT sum("Hours")
   FROM timesheets
  WHERE "Status" = 'Billable' AND "Date" between '2019-01-01' AND '2019-02-20'
) AS "Billable",

(SELECT sum("Hours")
   FROM timesheets
  WHERE "Status" = 'Non Billable' AND "Date" between '2019-01-01' AND '2019-02-20'
) AS "Non Billable"

 FROM timesheets
WHERE "Date" between '2019-01-01' AND '2019-02-20'
GROUP BY "Date", "Owner"
ORDER BY "Date", "Owner"
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the inner queries?

Comment: There's no grouping in the inner queries, so of course it will sum the whole result set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need subqueries. Since you are summing, you can use conditioning with `CASE WHEN`. If the condition matched put `Hours` else use `0` which does not have affect on summation. Check the solution below:

```
SELECT "Date", "Owner",
   sum(case when Status = 'Billable' then Hours else 0 end) billable,
   sum(case when Status = 'Non Billable' then Hours else 0 end) non_billable
 FROM timesheets
WHERE "Date" between '2019-01-01' AND '2019-02-20'
GROUP BY "Date", "Owner"
ORDER BY "Date", "Owner"
```

Comment: Totally epic answer...so simple I would never have thought of it. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your  subquery are group by  Date, Owner   and you have total sum .. 
for obtaion a sum groped by  Date, Owner you could sum directly  using  use a  conditional sum

```
    SELECT Date, Owner, 
        sum(case when Status = 'Billable' then Hours else 0 end) `Billable`
        sum(case when Status = 'Non Billable' then Hours else 0 end) `Non Billable`
     FROM timesheets
    WHERE Date between '2019-01-01' AND '2019-02-20'
    GROUP BY Date, Owner
    ORDER BY Date, Owner
```